# Modificar contenido de un arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Necesito hacer un Banco en el cual los saldos de los cuentahabientes se actualicen después de hacer una transacción.
La información de mis clientes está almacenada en un arraylist y necesito que únicamente lo haga el saldo.
La información de los clientes está dada por no. de cuenta,nombre,edad,direccion,saldo,telefono.

Intente con el comando arraylist.set(index,"string"); pero no funciona del todo pues mi información no es completamente un String.

```
public void subMenu(){       

Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);   

System.out.printf( "Inserte su ID" );  
opcion1 = entrada.nextInt();     

System.out.println("\t\t Menu");    
System.out.println("\t\t  Elija una opcion ");    
System.out.println("\t\t 1. Consultar informacion");    
System.out.println("\t\t 2. Consultar saldo");    
System.out.println("\t\t 3. Realizar un deposito");    
System.out.println("\t\t 4. Realizar un retiro");    
System.out.println("\t\t 5. Traspaso");   
System.out.println("\t\t 6. Modificar datos");   
System.out.println("\t\t 7. Eliminar su registro");     
opcionMenu = entrada.nextInt();   

AperturaDeCuenta cuenta11 = new AperturaDeCuenta(); 

String info = cuenta11.toString(); 
String str[] = info.split("\n"); 


// Crear pacientes  
Clientes cliente1 = new Clientes(123423796, "Juan Camaney", 21, "Eje central no. 27 Coyoac•n CDMX", 10534.879, "5532678909");  
Clientes cliente2 = new Clientes(206317648, "Vanessa Camaney", 18, "Miguel Quevedo no. 456 Coyoac•n CDMX", 1500.12, "5578360921");  
Clientes cliente3 = new Clientes(314460847, "Miguel Camaney", 19, "La avante no.43 Iztapalapa CDMX", 22434.09, "5534812209");  
Clientes cliente4 = new Clientes(422990352, "Brandon Camaney", 32, "El rosal no.12 Benito Juare CDMX", 28332.02, "5528203756");  
Clientes cliente5 = new Clientes(597573100, "Diego Camaney", 26, "Potrero no. 89 Venustiano Carranza CDMX", 16576, "5527784148"); 
Clientes cliente6 = new Clientes(609337823, "Araceli Camaney", 47, "Florida no. 70 Viveros Coyoacán CDMX", 5486.25, "5534752309"); 
Clientes cliente7 = new Clientes(786685244,"Victor Camaney",30,"Campestre Churubusco no.90 Miguel Hidalgo CDMX", 6721109, "5634218860"); 
Clientes cliente8 = new Clientes(865979733, "Hugo Camaney",24,"Mujeres ilustres no. 36 Iztacalco CDMX",7744687.67,"5610943299"); 
Clientes cliente9 = new Clientes(962970253, "Páez Camaney",58,"Traineras no. 677 Xochimilco CDMX",56313086,"5546272100"); 
Clientes cliente10 = new Clientes(105903215, "Johan Camaney",24,"Mujeres ilustres no. 36 Iztacalco CDMX",706742680.21,"5637502184"); 
Clientes cliente11= new Clientes(numeroDeCuenta, nombre,edad,domicilio,monto,telefono); 

List<Clientes> clientes = new ArrayList<Clientes>();  
clientes.add(cliente1);  
clientes.add(cliente2);  
clientes.add(cliente3);  
clientes.add(cliente4);  
clientes.add(cliente5);  
clientes.add(cliente6);  
clientes.add(cliente7); 
clientes.add(cliente8); 
clientes.add(cliente9); 
clientes.add(cliente10); 
clientes.add(cliente11); 


//*******METODOS DE ACCESO ********//    

switch (opcionMenu){    
  case 1:    

    System.out.println("\nNumero de Cuenta: " + clientes.get(opcion1).getNumeroDeCuenta() +   
                       "\n Nombre: " + clientes.get(opcion1).getNombre() +   
                       "\n Edad: "  + clientes.get(opcion1).getEdad() +  
                       "\n Domicilio: " + clientes.get(opcion1).getDomicilio() +    
                       "\n Monto: " +  clientes.get(opcion1).getMonto() +   
                       "\n Telefono: " + clientes.get(opcion1).getTelefono());  
    break;   
  case 2:   
    System.out.println("Ver mi saldo " + clientes.get(opcion1).getMonto() );   
    break;   
  case 3:    
    System.out.println("cantidad a depositar" );  
    deposito = entrada.nextInt();  
    saldoIng = clientes.get(opcion1).getMonto();  
    saldo = deposito + saldoIng;  
    System.out.println("Tu saldo era " + clientes.get(opcion1).getMonto() + ", Cantidad ingresada " + deposito + ", Tu saldo actual es " + saldo ); 
  break;
```

Comment: Perdóname pero, no entiendo bien tu pregunta. Cuál es tu duda? qué es lo que quieres lograr?, tu descripción no es bien detallada. Otra cosa, el ID que pides al inicio es el número de cuenta?.

Answer (score 1):

Si he entendido bien tu problema, las posibles soluciones que puedes implementar serían:

1. Implementar el hashcode(), equals() y el compareTo(), pudiendo hacer que tu compareTo() sea por no de cliente y así buscar fácilmente el cliente del cual actualizar su saldo.
2. Hacer un foreach en el cual vayas comprobando todos los elementos de tu ArrayList y luego vas comprobando posición por posición su no de cliente y si es correcto le actualizas al nuevo saldo.

Comment: ¿Podrías ilustrar tus propuestas con código?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a poner esto despues de hacer la transaccion, siempre y cuando tengas el correspondiente setter de monto en la clase Cliente:

```
clientes.get(opcion1).setMonto(nuevaCantidad);
```

Si modificas el objeto fuera de la lista, tambien se modifica dentro de esta.

Answer (score 0):

Para que el metodo funcione debes de sobreescribir en tu clase cliente los siguientes metodos equal

```
    @Override
public boolean equals (Object obj) {

        if (obj instanceof Cliente) {

        Cliente tmp = (Cliente) obj;

            if (this.id.equals(tmp.id)) { return true; } else { return false; }

    } else { return false; }
```

El metodo hascode

```
@Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.id;
    }
```

he implementas interfaz comparte to

```
public class Cliente implements Comparable<Cliente>{


    public int compareTo(Cliente o) {

        int resultado=0;

        if (this.id<o.id) {   resultado = -1;      }

        else if (this.id>o.id) {    resultado = 1;      }

        else {

              resultado = 0;   }

        }

        return resultado;

    }

}
```

en el main

```
List<Clientes> clientes = new ArrayList<Clientes>();
Cliente c = new Cliente(id,...);
int index= c,IDdget();
Cliente nuevo = (id,..);  
clientes.set(index, nuevo)
```

Comment: Gracias brother